# ¿Cómo puedo llamar a una función con parámetros desde un botón?

Tags: java, java-swing, botón

He hecho un programita que muestra una tabla en un JTable, y quiero pasarlo a excel. La función la tengo y funciona bien, pero querría que esta se llamara al hacer click en un JButton

```
public class Proyecto_horarios  extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

  // Exportado de tabla a archivo Excel
  public static void exportarExcel(JTable t) throws IOException {}



    JButton boton1 = new JButton("Boton");
    JFrame ventana1 = new JFrame();

    // Muestreo de ventana para la tabla
public Proyecto_horarios(JScrollPane parametroScrollPane) {
    super("Visor de jornadas");

    // Agregamos el botón y JScrollPane al contenedor. PRIMERO EL BOTÓN

    getContentPane().add(boton1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    getContentPane().add(parametroScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //boton1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(boton1.getParent().getWidth(), 0));
    // Posicionamos el botón y le otorgamos un tamaño
    boton1.setBounds(450,570,100,50);
        //boton1.setSize(150,150);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true); 
    // Llama a la acción que realiza el botón al pulsarlo
    boton1.addActionListener(this);


    // Manejamos la salida de la ventana
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    } 
    });

 }
////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Manejamos la acción del botón
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource()==boton1) {

        try{

            System.exit(0);  
        } 
        catch(Exception excep) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}


// Clase main
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {........
```

La idea es poder llamar a la función *"exportarExcel(JTable t)"* desde las acciones del botón, pero al requerir un parámetro que se trata en la función *"main"*, ando un poco perdido. De momento el botón lo único que hace es cerrar la ventana (era para probarlo).

¿Me podríais orientar un poco?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres que la clase Proyecto_horarios pueda exportar una tabla, necesitas que la clase tenga referencia a esa tabla.

```
public class Proyecto_horarios  extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JTable tablaAExportar; 

    // Exportado de tabla a archivo Excel
    public static void exportarExcel(JTable t) throws IOException {}

    public asignaTabla(JTable tabla) {
        tablaAExportar = tabla;
    }
```

Luego en donde escuchamos acción:

```
// Manejamos la acción del botón
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource()==boton1) {

    try{
        exportarExcel(tablaAExportar);
        System.exit(0);  
    } 
    catch(Exception excep) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Y como mencionas que la tabla se genera por alguna razón en el main, entonces :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   JTable tablaAExportar = ???
   Proyecto_horarios proyecto = new Proyecto_horarios();
   proyecto.asignaTabla(tablaAExportar);

   //etc, etc
```

}